# Standard User can't add/edit custom setting record in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created a custom settings object with two fields. I have also created a Apex controller , and a Visual Force Page to update/edit the custom settings. As a system administrator I can edit the custom settings using that form. But when I login as a standard user the form fields are not showing up. I can't add custom setting even through Setup->Develop->CustomSettings and clicking on manage, when I am logged in as standard user. I have made both my controller and Visual force page permissions to be accesible by any one.

Below is my controller code,

```
   public class XYZSettingsController
     {
     public  XYZSettings__c mySettings {get; set;}
     public XYZSettings__c myOrgSettings{get; set;}

     public XYZSettingsController()
        {

          mySettings = XYZSettings__c.getValues(System.Userinfo.getUserId());
          myOrgSettings = XYZSettings__c.getInstance();
            if(mySettings == null)
              {
              mySettings = new XYZSettings__c(SetupOwnerId=System.Userinfo.getUserId());
              }    

         }
    public String getOrgUrl()
    {
    return   myOrgSettings.XYZ_Url__c;
    }

    public String getOrgEmail()
    {
            return   myOrgSettings.XYZ_Email__c;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
            return   mySettings.XYZ_Url__c;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {

           return   mySettings.XYZ_Email__c;
    }

    public PageReference save() {

      if(mySettings.id == null){                   
           upsert mySettings;
             }
      else{
           update mySettings;
             }
      return null;
    }
    }
```

And below is my Visual Force page,

```
<apex:page Controller="XYZSettingsController" title="Edit XYZ access settings">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pagemessage severity="info" strength="1">
     Your default XYZ platform url is: {!OrgUrl} and Email is: {!OrgEmail}
     <br></br>
      You can override it in the settings below
    </apex:pagemessage> 
   <apex:pageBlock title="Edit XYZ settings" mode="edit">
  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>  
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">  
            <apex:inputField value="{!mySettings.XYZ_Url__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!mySettings.XYZ_Email__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this issue and answered it over on Salesforce. Refer to my answer there for a work around. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/giving-users-access-to-a-specific-custom-setting-without-granting-them-customize/45079#45079

Answer (score 0):

Users with the "Standard User" profile can not write to Custom Settings objects. To do this you need to grant users the "Customize Application" permission and this in turn requires the View Setup Configuration permission which is likely undesirable.

Your best bet here is to use a custom object instead for storing the user's settings.

On another note: Your getters for the email and URL fields are redundant, you can just use `{!mySettings.XYZ_Url__c}` etc. as you've done with the input fields, and for better formatting and character escaping you might want to consider using `<apex:outputField value="{!mySettings.XYZ_Url__c}"/>`.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thanks for replying. This is a new Custom Settings object. So I think the field level security settings are not applicable? Yeah I will try cloning the profile and changing this. Am right now in a developer account. Will that matter anyway?

Comment: Ah apologies! Developer account shouldn't affect it, but on the other hand I've never tried writing to a custom settings record — I suspect it isn't possible! As far as I'm aware, the purpose of custom settings is to maintain lists of data relating to an application which may not change but you don't want to be hardcoded.

Comment: @LaceySnr - not entirely; they serve dual purposes, one of which is application global config, but the other is user-specific preferences (a la Windows Registry etc).

Comment: @tamizhgeek -- make sure your custom settings object is a "Hierarchy" type with "Public" visibility.

Comment: @jkraybill I checked those type and visibility. Both are set right. I couldn't get it to work. So what I did is wrote a proxy controller which just gets the values from the form, and call a another 'without sharing' controller which actually updates the custom settings record.

Comment: This is very puzzling. I do this all the time without any issues. Yes, calling out "without sharing" would make the class declaration look cleaner, but otherwise there is no logical explanation (that I can think of) which would make a "proxy" class with the same access settings as the calling class any different than the calling class whatsoever. But I'm glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to create similar hierarchy custom settings from within a Flow, and ended up having to configure the Flow to run in System Context.

[image]

And then here's where we created the custom setting record for the user; just be sure to set the SetupOwnerId field:

[image]